# Line number information in Spring XML Namespace Handler

Tags: java, xml, spring

I'm writing custom Spring namespace handler (Java). If the XML is invalid, I'd like to report error message that will include line number (in the parsed document), so that user knows where to look. However, I don't know how to retrieve line number from DOM objects or otherwise.

Note that I'm talking about errors that are not discovered by XSD validation (those report line numbers correctly).

Is it even possible to get such information from inside Namespace handler?

Thanks,
Ondrej

Comment: Instead of line number, which greatly depends on formatting and stuff like that, you could publish the XPath of the offending node. This should be easier to get (at least on dom-based parsers) and it still can point to the unique offending node.

Comment: Good point, although I actually think that it's easier to find offending element by line number. However, I can go with xpath as well if it's really easier to retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the SAX parser you can extend the [DefaultLocator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler.html) class and register a [Locator](http://www.saxproject.org/apidoc/org/xml/sax/Locator.html) in setDocumentLocator method. The locator gets notified when an event occurs and therefore you can call getLineNumber() method to obtain the line number of interest.

Comment: Well, the parser is instantiated by Spring and I don't know how to access it (and I guess it's DOM parser anyway). All I have at hand is the Element object and Spring's ParserContext.